# boost::asio::ssl memory leaks, even though use the boost::asio::ssl example

Tags: ssl, boost, memory-leaks, asio

This is the `boost::asio::ssl` example, it has no memory leaks:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(_WINDOWS_)
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
#endif
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_context io_context;

        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type endpoints =
            resolver.resolve("127.0.0.1", "9443");

        boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
        ctx.load_verify_file("ca.pem");

        client c(io_context, ctx, endpoints);

        io_context.run();

        while (getchar() != 'q');
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But, if I change the code to the following:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(_WINDOWS_)
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
#endif
    try
    {
        // just used a thread to execute the ssl test,the rest of the code is exactly the same
        std::thread([]()
        {
            boost::asio::io_context io_context;

            boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type endpoints =
                resolver.resolve("127.0.0.1", "9443");

            boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
            ctx.load_verify_file("ca.pem");

            client c(io_context, ctx, endpoints);

            io_context.run();

            while (getchar() != 'q');
        }).join();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

then, there is a memory leak:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{2182} normal block at 0x000000000034C8B0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <        > 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{128} normal block at 0x000000000035AB30, 520 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

I found the `asio::ssl` memory leaks for a long time, but never solved it, and I found if `io_context::run` is not called in the main thread, then there will be a memory leak. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a leak. Any memory allocated in static constructors may be falsely identified as a leak.

To resolve this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "MemLeakInstrumentation.h"
#include "MemLeakListener.h"

#include "PreventFalseMemoryLeaksFromStatics.hpp"
static int q = prevent_false_memory_leaks_from_statics( L"UnitTest.CouloirAFX" );

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   testing::InitGoogleTest( &argc, argv );

   auto& listeners = testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->listeners();
   listeners.Append( new gte::MemLeakListener );

   const auto result = RUN_ALL_TESTS();
   return result;
}

static int prevent_false_memory_leaks_from_statics( Couloir::String UnitTestName )
{
   Couloir::Directory BoostStaticInit( L"C:\\Dev\\Couloir\\Generic\\PFM\\UnitTest.CouloirPFM" );
   boost::asio::io_context ioc;
   ssl::context AsioStaticInit{ ssl::context::sslv23_client };
```